How to delete a program that won’t remove?
I am not able to uninstall the software named "Adobe Creative Cloud" which gets installed when I install Adobe Premiere Pro.
I uninstalled Adobe Premiere Pro, but the "Adobe Creative Cloud" is not getting uninstalled. I am told that I have an Adobe product installed that would require "Adobe Creative Cloud" and so it will not install.

As you can see here

The Creative Cloud desktop app can only be uninstalled if all Creative Cloud apps (such as Photoshop, Illustrator, and Premiere Pro) have already been uninstalled.

So if you want to keep Adobe Premiere Pro you cannot uninstall Creative Cloud.
If instead you have deleted Premiere and want to uninstall Creative Cloud too, you can follow the above link or this one to complete the procedure.
